# Segmentation fault while iterating through list

Tags: c

I'm getting segmentation fault when trying to access current_nap->next (sometimes even on current->value->napok but that's rare). I don't get why this happens because I can iterate through NapList with the functions in its header without any problem. Could you help me, please?

Here is my code:

```
void saveToFile()
{
    int g;
    g = open("save.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    JelentkezesList *current = jelentkezesek;

    char line[] = "";
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("eddig ok\n");
        strncpy(line, "", sizeof(line));
        printf("eddig ok2\n");
        strcat(line, "{");
        strcat(line, current->value->nev);
        strcat(line, ";");
        strcat(line, current->value->cim);
        strcat(line, ";");
        printf("eddig ok3\n");

        NapList *current_nap = current->value->napok;
        printf("eddig ok4\n");

        while (current_nap != NULL)
        {
            printf("eddig ok5\n");

            if (current_nap->value == HETFO)
            {
                strcat(line, "0");
                printf("hetfo\n");
            }
            else if (current_nap->value == KEDD)
            {
                strcat(line, "1");
                printf("kedd\n");
            }
            else if (current_nap->value == SZERDA)
            {
                strcat(line, "2");
                printf("szerda\n");
            }
            else if (current_nap->value == CSUTORTOK)
            {
                strcat(line, "3");
                printf("csutortok\n");
            }
            else if (current_nap->value == PENTEK)
            {
                strcat(line, "4");
                printf("pentek\n");
            }
            else if (current_nap->value == SZOMBAT)
            {
                strcat(line, "5");
                printf("szombat\n");
            }
            else if (current_nap->value == VASARNAP)
            {
                strcat(line, "6");
                printf("vasarnap\n");
            }
            printf("eddig ok5.1\n");

            //if (current_nap->next != NULL)
            //{
            strcat(line, ",");
            //}

            printf("eddig ok6\n");
            current_nap = current_nap->next;
            printf("eddig ok7\n");
        }

        strcat(line, "}\n");
        if (write(g, line, sizeof(line)) != sizeof(line))
        {
            printf("Hiba a mentés során!");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("eddig ok8\n");
        current = current->next;
        printf("eddig ok9\n");
    }
    close(g);
    printf("%s", "Sikeres mentés!");
}
```

Here are my headers:

JelentkezesList

```
#include "string_utils.h"
#include "jelentkezes.h"
#include "nap_list.h"

#ifndef JELENTKEZES_LIST_H
#define JELENTKEZES_LIST_H

typedef struct jelentkezes_node
{
    Jelentkezes *value;
    struct jelentkezes_node *next;
} JelentkezesList;

void printJelentkezesList(JelentkezesList *head)
{
    JelentkezesList *current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printJelentkezes(current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void printJelentkezesListForDay(JelentkezesList *head, Nap nap)
{
    JelentkezesList *current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (containsNap(current->value->napok, nap))
        {
            printf("\n");
            printJelentkezes(current->value);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void addToJelentkezesList(JelentkezesList **list, Jelentkezes *value)
{
    JelentkezesList *current = *list;
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        current = (JelentkezesList *)malloc(sizeof(JelentkezesList));
        Jelentkezes *j = value;
        j->azonosito = 0;
        current->value = j;
        current->next = NULL;
        *list = current;
    }
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        current->next = (JelentkezesList *)malloc(sizeof(JelentkezesList));
        Jelentkezes *j = value;
        j->azonosito = current->value->azonosito + 1;
        current->next->value = j;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

Jelentkezes *findJelentkezes(JelentkezesList *list, int id)
{
    Jelentkezes *result = NULL;
    JelentkezesList *current = list;

    while (current != NULL && result == NULL)
    {
        if (current->value->azonosito == id)
        {
            result = current->value;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    return result;
}

void deleteJelentkezes(JelentkezesList **list, Jelentkezes *j)
{
    JelentkezesList *current = *list;

    if (current->value->azonosito == j->azonosito)
    {
        *list = current->next;
        free(current);
        return;
    }

    while (current->next->value->azonosito != j->azonosito)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    JelentkezesList *toDelete = current->next;
    current->next = current->next->next;
    free(toDelete);
    *list = current;
}

JelentkezesList *createJelentkezesList()
{
    JelentkezesList *jelentkezes_head = NULL;
    return jelentkezes_head;
}

#endif
```

Jelentkezes

```
#include "string_utils.h"
#include "nap.h"
#include "nap_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef JELENTKEZES_H
#define JELENTKEZES_H

typedef struct
{
    int azonosito;
    String nev;
    String cim;
    NapList *napok;
} Jelentkezes;

Jelentkezes *createJelentkezes(String *nev, String *cim, NapList *napok)
{
    Jelentkezes *j = (Jelentkezes *)malloc(sizeof(Jelentkezes));
    j->azonosito = -1;
    j->nev = *nev;
    j->cim = *cim;
    j->napok = napok;
    return j;
}

void printJelentkezes(Jelentkezes *j)
{
    printf("Azonosító: %d\n", j->azonosito);
    printf("Név: %s, Cím: %s\n", j->nev, j->cim);
    printf("Munkavállalás napjai: ");
    printNapList(j->napok);
}

#endif
```

NapList

```
#include "string_utils.h"
#include "nap.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef NAP_LIST_H
#define NAP_LIST_H

typedef struct nap_node
{
    Nap value;
    struct nap_node *next;
} NapList;

void printNapList(NapList *head)
{
    NapList *current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->value == HETFO)
        {
            printf("hétfő");
        }
        else if (current->value == KEDD)
        {
            printf("kedd");
        }
        else if (current->value == SZERDA)
        {
            printf("szerda");
        }
        else if (current->value == CSUTORTOK)
        {
            printf("csütörtök");
        }
        else if (current->value == PENTEK)
        {
            printf("péntek");
        }
        else if (current->value == SZOMBAT)
        {
            printf("szombat");
        }
        else if (current->value == VASARNAP)
        {
            printf("vasárnap");
        }

        if (current->next != NULL)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }

        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void addToNapList(NapList **list, Nap value)
{
    NapList *current = *list;
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        current = (NapList *)malloc(sizeof(NapList));
        current->value = value;
        current->next = NULL;
        *list = current;
    }
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        current->next = (NapList *)malloc(sizeof(NapList));
        current->next->value = value;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

bool containsNap(NapList *nl, Nap nap)
{
    NapList *current = nl;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->value == nap)
            return true;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}

NapList *createNapList()
{
    NapList *nap_head = NULL;
    return nap_head;
}

#endif
```

Comment: `char line[] = "";` `strcat(line, "{");` is invalid. `line` has only 1 byte. `write(g, line, sizeof(line))` `sizeof` is not `strlen`.

Comment: C arrays don't grow. You need to either give their size at definition, or (for char arrays) initialize them with a string of appropriate (maximum expected) length. What happens when you use `char line[4096] = "";`?

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, somehow I missed that while being blinded by looking for the problem at how the pointers were handled. Now it works like a charm :)